# Alternative to Toggle

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I have a basic show hide toggle. It works on everything but iPhone and it's driving me crazy.

Is there an alternative to the following javascript that does not use the toggle function?

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pic_you_click_on").on('click', function(){
        $("#display").toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<img class="pic_you_click_on" src="images.png"></img>
<ul id="display" class="div_to_appear">
    <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home"class="scroll">Home</a> </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#display {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with iPhone?

Comment: On android or desktop - including safari, the toggle functions as it should. On iphone nothing happens at all.

Comment: maybe try to use **click** jQuery func instead of **on('click...'**

Comment: Can be a capture/bubble issue? CAn you provide a demo?

Comment: does my website help? It's up and running and you can see the issue?

Comment: If so it's shereewalker.com it's the hamburger nav below 650px

Comment: Tip: @Sheree Walker. Use touch(touchstart) events for mobile. Touchstart faster than click

Comment: Trying to build a demo now

@SheraliTurdiyev is that just a case of: 

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".pic_you_click_on").on('touchstart', function(){
           $("#display").toggle();
       });
   });

Comment: Touchstart does not work, neither does click. I give up!

Comment: Also, use hammer.js for events(TAP, SWIPE, ....) instead of jQuery click and touchstrat

Comment: Try this instead of toggle.       `$(...).css('display',isShow ? 'none' : 'blablah'); isShow = !isShow;`

Comment: I don't really understand that. I'm sorry - I have no real javascript knowledge.

Comment: Okay so - I started again by placing a completely new toggle button at the start of my document. I only used minimal styling and presto it worked. I don't know what it was about my previous toggle but I suspect z-indexes might have had something to do with it. Good news -  I carefully amended the new button and it's working again and the bad news - I wasted an entire 2 days of my life! Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: And once again it has stopped working.

Comment: If you can share your code in jsfiddle, i can help you

Comment: Okay thankyou! I'm pretty desperate now. I've never used jsfiddle but I'll try now

Comment: I'm really sorry but I can't even get jsfiddle to work. I have concluded though the the issue seems to occur when I fix the position of the hamburger menu.  When left it functions but as soon as I fix it, the button stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I know what the problem is.
Animate Css. I used it to apply an animation effect to my header that flies in. What I did not know, it that using animations can often mess with your stacking order, particularly fixed elements. See article below.

http://daneden.me/2012/04/22/css-transforms-and-z-index/

I had to strip back the whole site and place each element one by one, checking it each time.
The moment I added the effect, it turned to custard. Apparently this is common knowledge... Not to me! I've removed it and the button now functions.